# Parse multiple date formats to a specific format

Tags: python, date, date-formatting, date-parsing

In my application user can enter dates in format of dd/mm/yy  with date separator variations(like they can use /,- or space as a seperator). They can also put 4 digit year or 2  digit year and they can also enter 3 letter code for a month or a 2 digit code for month. Once I have the date from the user I want to validate that the format is a valid date format and then convert it to '%d-%b-%Y'. In the below function I am validating the date format, but I am not sure how to handle all the mixed date separator formats like 01/12 2013, 01-12 13, 01 12/2013 etc. There can be loads of these

```
def validate_date(date_str):
    formats = ['%d-%b-%Y', '%d-%b-%y', '%d-%m-%Y', '%d-%m-%y',
               '%d/%m/%Y', '%d/%m/%y', '%d/%b/%Y', '%d/%b/%y',
               '%d %m %Y', '%d %m %y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b %y',
                '%d%m%Y', '%d%b%y', '%d%b%Y', '%d %b/%Y'] 
    data = None

    for fmt in formats:
        try:
            dateValue = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, fmt).date()
            data = dateValue
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass

    if data is None:
    # invalid date format
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, perhaps you want to look at [`python-dateutils`](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) instead; it's `parse()` function already handles these formats, and more.

Comment: I don't think you should allow them, as they do not represent a valid file format in any locale. If you look at the lib proposed by Martijn, you will see variations revolve in the order of d/m/y, not in a mix of separators. You may also work around the problem by forcing days, months and year to be entered separately (not perfect), or provide a calendar widget

Comment: Thanks for your replies.I did suggest to the client(owner of the application) that we would be better off using calendar widget but they still want that user should be allowed to enter dates with mixed seperators

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all chars not being digit into spaces and then parse it using much less formats.